# Retrieving a Document from a QueryResult with OpenCMIS

Tags: java, opencmis

I'm using the Apache Chemistry OpenCMIS java library. Given a QueryResult (e.g. I found a document or a bunch of documents by searching on metadata properties), is this a reasonable way to retrieve the Document object itself? Or is there a more efficient way?

```java
ItemIterable<QueryResult> results = session.query("SELECT * FROM cmis:document WHERE cmis:name LIKE 'test%'", false);

for(QueryResult hit: results) {
        Document document = (Document) session.getObject(session.createObjectId((String) hit.getPropertyValueById("cmis:objectId"))); 
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [Session.queryObjects()](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/0.11.0/maven/apidocs/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/api/Session.html#queryObjects%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.OperationContext%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

For me this works perfectly

```
String myType = "my:documentType";

// get the query name of cmis:objectId
ObjectType type = session.getTypeDefinition(myType);
PropertyDefinition<?> objectIdPropDef = type.getPropertyDefinitions().get(PropertyIds.OBJECT_ID);
String objectIdQueryName = objectIdPropDef.getQueryName();

String queryString = "SELECT " + objectIdQueryName + " FROM " + type.getQueryName();

// execute query
ItemIterable<QueryResult> results = session.query(queryString, false);

for (QueryResult qResult : results) {
   String objectId = qResult.getPropertyValueByQueryName(objectIdQueryName);
   Document doc = (Document) session.getObject(session.createObjectId(objectId));
}
```

Found here: https://chemistry.apache.org/java/examples/example-process-query-results.html